# While loop in robotframework (check periodically status bar in desktop application)

Tags: python, python-2.7, autoit, robotframework

Is there some alternative for while loop in Robotframework? 
I need to check progress status in status bar in my desktop application. For checking I'm using AutoitLibrary and read message from progress label.

My temporary solution is with recursive keyword call. But, when progress takes more time than usual, test case fail with maximum recursive call message.
So, I need some kind of while loop. How to implement this without recursion?

Comment: What have you coded so far?
You can just use an infinite while loop in AutoIt with a `Sleep(1)` after your status check. This will cause the process not to consume all processor time but to respond immediately.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [wait until keyword succeeds](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds) keyword to do this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you say `periodical`, think `AdlibRegister`:

```
AdlibRegister("ReadProgressStatus", 3000) ; to stop it: AdlibUnRegister("ReadProgressStatus")
While True
    ; alternatively: do your "normal" Job
    Sleep(1000)
    ConsoleWrite("working..." & @CRLF)
WEnd

Func ReadProgressStatus()
    ; read Status bar etc...
    ConsoleWrite("checking status" & @CRLF)
EndFunc   ;==>ReadProgressStatus
```